# In the figure, $AB//CD$. If $P$ is midpoint of $BC$ then prove that area of triangle $ADP$ = area of triangle $(APB+DCP)$

Tags: geometry

Let $A,B,C,D$ the vertices, where $A$ is on the top right corner and the vertices are arranged in clockwise direction $A,B,C,D$. I could prove that the triangle $APB+ DCP=1/2$ of $ABCD$. But I'm getting problems to prove that $ADP = 1/2$ of $ABCD$. Please help me prove it.

Comment: What's the figure that you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Draw a figure. $ABCD$ is a trapezoid. You can easily see that the figure is made out of three triangles $APB$, $DCP$, and $ADP$, so the sum of the areas of the triangles is the area of the trapezoid. Then if $$A_{APB}+A_{DCP}=\frac 12 A_{ABCD}$$and $$A_{APB}+A_{DCP}+A_{ADP}=A_{ABCD}$$ then:
$$A_{ADP}=A_{ABCD}-(A_{APB}+A_{DCP})=A_{ABCD}-\frac 12 A_{ABCD}=\frac 12 A_{ABCD}$$

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your figure is trapezium, but if that were the case then figure would be formed by the three parts abp, dcp and apd. But i think thats not the case seeing your description. So please elaborate about your figure

Comment: Sry, meant to leave a comment

Answer (score 0):

Let draw another line from $P$ which is also parallel to $AB$ and $CD$ and let the line intersects with $AD$ at $E$. Then, rotate the quadrilateral $CPED$ by $180^{\circ}$ about $P$ and get new quadrilateral, $C'PE'D'$. Note that $CP=BC$ so $B$ intersects with $C'$. Also because $AB//DC$ , $A$ , $B'$ , $C'$ are colinear. Thus, $AEE'D'$ is a parallelogram so, $$A_{DCP}+A_{ABP}=A_{BD'P}+A_{ABP}=A_{AD'P}=A_{E'D'P}+A_{AEP}=A_{DPE}+A_{AEP}=A_{ADP}$$